# Trouble with predict function in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I loaded the inbuilt R data 'women' which has a tabular data of average American women's height and corresponding weight. this table has 15 rows. Using this data I am trying to predict the weight for specific values of height. I made a linear model first and gave new values to predict. But R still comes up with the 15 figures from the original data.

I am a beginner in regression so please tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
 data()
> women<-data.frame(women)
> names(women)
[1] "height" "weight"
> plot(women$weight~women$height)
> model<-lm(women$weight~women$height,data=women)
> new<-data.frame(height=c(82,83,84,85))
> wgt.prediction<-predict(model,new)
Warning message:
'newdata' had 4 rows but variables found have 15 rows 
 > wgt.prediction
   1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9          10       11       12       13 
112.5833 116.0333 119.4833 122.9333 126.3833 129.8333 133.2833 136.7333 140.1833 143.6333 147.0833 150.5333 153.9833 
  14       15 
157.4333 160.8833
```

Comment: Try building your model using `model<-lm(weight~height,data=women)` and try to predict again.

Comment: Thank you. It worked,I will always keep this in mind from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Note that extrapolating predictions outside the range of the original data can give poor answers; however, ignoring that try the following.

First, it is not necessary to use `data()` or `data.frame`.  `women` will be available to you anyways and it is already a data frame.

Also, the model's independent variable was specified in the question as `women$height` but the prediction specified it as `height`. It does not know that `women$height` and `height` are the same.

Replace all your code with this:

```
fo <- weight ~ height
model <- lm(fo, women)
heigths <- c(82, 83, 84, 85)
weights <- predict(model, data.frame(height = heights))
```

giving:

```
> weights
       1        2        3        4 
195.3833 198.8333 202.2833 205.7333
```

To plot the data with the predictions (i.e. with `weights`) and the regression line defined by `model` (continued after graph):

```
plot(fo, women, xlim = range(c(height, heights)), ylim = range(c(weight, weights)))
points(weights ~ heights, col = "red", pch = 20)
abline(model)
```

[image: screenshot]

Although normally one uses `predict`, given the problem introduced by using $ in the formula, an alternative using your original formulation would be to calculate the predictions like this:

```
model0 <- lm(women$weight ~ women$height)
cbind(1, 82:85) %*% coef(model0)
```

giving:

```
         [,1]
[1,] 195.3833
[2,] 198.8333
[3,] 202.2833
[4,] 205.7333
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# example dataset
dt = data.frame(mtcars)

# build 2 models
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = dt)
m2 = lm(dt$mpg ~ dt$wt, data = dt)

# new data (to predict)
dt_new = data.frame(wt = c(3.1, 3.5, 4.2))

# check if predictions work
predict(m1, dt_new)
predict(m2, dt_new)
```

The first `predict` will work as the model's dependent variable is `wt` and the new data have the variable `wt` as well.

The second `predict` will not work because the model's dependent variable is `dt$wt` so every time the model will go back to `dt` to get the variable `wt`. In fact, no matter what your new dataset looks like, the model will try to predict using `dt$wt`.

Comment: Thank you. Great insight. never thought about this.